# How do I set the timeout of a SocketServer in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I want to use `server.get_request()` to receive requests, but I want it to timeout after 500 milliseconds. Is this correct? Doesn't seem to work... thanks.

```
class UDPServer(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    timeout = .500

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = SocketServer.UDPServer(('localhost', '12345'), UDPServer)
    server.get_request()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel there are some places wrong:

1. The class derived from `SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler` should be `MyUDPServerHandler` or something else, but should not be UDPServer which is a built-in class in SocketServer
2. It should be `server = SocketServer.UDPServer(('localhost', '12345'), MyUDPServerhandler)`
3. Then maybe it should be `server.timeout = .500`. And define a `handle_timeout()` method

Comment: You are right about the naming convention. I overlooked that. Surprisingly, this was not causing any trouble. But I see, it's just a variable, accessible via the dot operator. I didn't understand how to set it. Thanks.